# Using set location relative method to set the JFrame to center, still appearing to the up left of the screen

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {                
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try { 
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                new megui().setVisible(true);
                new megui().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
//this method should set the frame to the center of the screen but it doesn't   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please describe your question clearly and add a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new megui().setVisible(true);
new megui().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

The set location is doing nothing because you are creating two frames (and only the first frame is actually visible).

The code should be:

```
MeGUI frame = new MeGUI();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Note, I changed your class names since classes should use capital letters for each word in the class name and acronyms should be upper cased as well.

But you should even use a more descriptive class name since "MeGUI" doesn't describe what the class does.